# Going to the same "instance" of an Intent/Activity in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent, instance

I have a menu in an Android application, and when I click one of the buttons to start a new activity I want the instance variables to keep their values even if I go back to the menu and start it again. 
This is what I've tried:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putBoolean("isFav",false);
            centralsIntent = new Intent("kth.blod.CENTRALS");
            centralsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            centralsIntent.putExtras(b);

            startActivity(centralsIntent);
        }
```

And in the manifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Comment: Try this intent on your call back to your menu activity: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. If you do so it wont be reinstantiated if its still running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think shared preferences are the easiest way to keep track of values you have set in one part of your application that you want to save and possibly modify upon returning from another part of the application.  See this link for [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).  See [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to see how to implement them.  Good luck!

Comment: The values I want preserved is actually an instance of a class, containing lists of objects. Those objects are filled with online content, and I don't want to have to fetch it again everytime someone goes back to the menu. Shared Preferences only seem to pass Strings and ints.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your question. When you say 'I have a menu', do you mean that the main activity (or first activity) is a menu? If that is the case, the user can select from the menu and your can start a new activity which then appears **on top of** the menu activity. As long as you don't call `finish()` on the menu activity it won't go away (in the normal case) and when the user returns to it all the instance variables will still contain whatever they had when the user started the new activity. Also, you shouldn't need **launchMode='singleTop'** for this as this is the standard default behaviour.

Or maybe I don't completely understand what your problem is...

Comment: Yes, the menu is the main activity, and the user will return to the menu activity when they return from my content activity. However, when I start the content activity again, the information in THAT activity is lost. This is the information I want preserved, in the content activity. So I would like to start the same "instance" of the content activity.

Comment: What you need to do then, in the content activity, is to have it store its state somewhere. I agree with @thomas.cloud that shared preferences is a reasonable place to do this. Or you can just write these things to a file. You will need to serialize the objects you want to save into byte streams or strings as appropriate to the method you want to use to store them.

Comment: Will this not be very consuming operations on a smartphone?  Mainly i have a class with 3 arraylists, with 5-10 objects in each. In each object there are ~10 strings. Pardon me if the question is dumb, but I haven't tried that before. 

Is it possible to pass entire instances of classes as shared preferences?

Comment: No, serializing a few hundred strings takes hardly any time at all (unless they are huge). And no, you cannot put an instance of a class (ie: an object) into the shared preferences. You must first serialize it into a String.